# Reaction centre in Photosystems of higher plants

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, photosynthesis, light, chloroplasts

In photosystems of higher plants, there are about 250-400 pigments (number wise) in a particular photosystem. Out of which,approx 170-180 pigments are of *chlorophyll a* molecules. And **any one** of them behaves as a *Reaction centre* in a photosystem.

My question is:

1. What are the factors and laws which decide **which** *chlorophyll a* molecule will work as a reaction centre?
2. What's the difference in **chlorophyll a molecules** present in reaction centres of PS I and PS II since they have different threshold energy. Is there any structural difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question...

> What are the factors and laws which decide which chlorophyll a molecule will work as a reaction centre?

... has **no** answer because it's based on a wrong premise: namely that, regarding the chlorophyll molecules, *"any one of them behaves as a Reaction centre in a photosystem"* (sic).

On the contrary, the special pair is **bound** to the reaction center's proteins (called D1 and D2). According to Berg (2002):

> The photochemistry of photosystem II begins with excitation of a special pair of chlorophyll molecules that are **bound** by the D1 and D2 subunits. (emphasis mine).

Regarding your second question, it was already answered [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/59283/24284).

---

Source: Berg JM, Tymoczko JL, Stryer L. Biochemistry. 5th edition. New York: W H Freeman; 2002. Available from: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21154/

Comment: Thank you Gerardo! It helped a lot =) may you please answer a question I recently posted. -https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/68218/11647

Answer (score 1):

Someone else too had asked your question no. 2. here [Photosystem 1 and 2; P680/P700; Chlorophyll a/b](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/59227/photosystem-1-and-2-p680-p700-chlorophyll-a-b/59232)

The answer basically quotes Molecular Biology 4 ed. by Lodish as follows.

"The chlorophylls in the two reaction centers differ in their light-absorption maxima because of differences in their protein environment."

[I could've just commented this but I can't locate add comment option on your post. Am new here.]

Comment: You couldn't find the *comment* option because you have less than 50 Reputation Points. Once you pass that threshold you'll be able to comment.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo. Could you please answer a question I have put up here https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/68190/what-is-the-primary-electron-donor-in-the-photosystem-1-and-photosystem-2