# Mobile carriers of Light reaction in higher plants

Tags: photosynthesis, light, membrane-transport, chloroplasts

The hydrogen carrier **PQ** and the electron carrier **PC** are the mobile carriers in light reaction facilitating electron transfer from PS II to PS I during non-cyclic process.

My question is -

1. How do they move in membrane, from PS II to cytochrome for PQ and cytochrome to PS I for PC?
   I do know the membrane is quasi-fluid in nature so it'll be easy for carriers to move in it but my question is how do they reach their destination? What's the driving force?

   Maybe they're just **arranged** that way on the membrane and some change like - because of change in density (when PQ accepts the H and converts to PQH2 ; *I'm not sure about the density change part*) which leads to change in side on which it's present or change in anything else, they reach their target?

Is my thinking correct?